# Android GCM error at server side when pushing notifications

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM for sending push notifications to devices with my app.

I have all the things ready and working, on my local machine that is. When I send a message to the device from the local machine, I get that message as notification, but when I host that page on my site and try to send message from there it says:

> "ERROR : INVALID REGISTRATION"

What could be the issue?

Comment: You are using java or php?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same Registration ID in the case that works (local machine) and the case that doesn't (from your site)? That error indicates you are using an invalid Registration ID.

Comment: @Brontok I am using .net as server side.

Comment: @Eran yes I am sure that the regId is same in both the cases.

Comment: @Eran as I am sending the message from local machine and uploading the same page without changing it.